# jquery blockui working strange with IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, jqgrid, jquery-blockui

i have a jqgrid and when i double click a row, i call jquery blockui as i load a dialogue.  In every browser the blockUI loading message shows up in the middle of the jqgrid perfectly but in IE8 it shows at the bottom of the grid all the way to the left and not overlaying:

[image]

If i put ie8 into compatibility mode it seems to work fine.

Is there any reason why jquery blockui can center the loading message properly in IE8 ?

Comment: I use blockUI and have never seen the problem in IE8. Could you include code fragment which can be used to reproduce the problem? Which version of blockUI you use? Version 2.37 from http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#download or some another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen that problem either.
I tend to  wrap my grid in a DIV and build the BlockUI on that:

```
<div id="PermissionsContainer">
    <table id="PermissionsGrid"></table>
    <div id="PermissionsPager"></div>    
</div>
```

and

```
$("#PermissionsContainer").block({ message: '... saving ...' });
```

Comment: looks good.  . IE 8 doesn't seem to like using the grid table div for this

Comment: @ooo: I used always also `jQuery('#main').block({...})` where `#main` is the id of the `div` which is direct parent of `<table>` and the pager `<div>`. I had no time any problems like LeftyX.

Comment: @Oleg - makes sense . .putting a container div solves the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `<!doctype html>` at the beginning of the page. It's work for me..